In R, how to use Chromote to download (or "save as") a file
In R and using Chromote, how could one download (or "Save as") a given file? For example, consider Wikipedia's tagline image: "https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-tagline-en.svg".
Then the following code navigates to that file:
library(chromote)
cs <- ChromoteSession$new()
cs$Page$navigate("https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-tagline-en.svg")

But is there a way for me to download that file to a pre-specified location, as if I was navigating to it and the clicking the right-click menu option "save as"?
PS: I am aware of the download.file() command. I am trying to learn how to achieve that specifically using Chromote, to help me solve some more intricate web-scrapping problems.

Not an answer but too long for a comment. Just hope to be helpful.
I managed to get the code of the svg document. Like this:
Sys.setenv(CHROMOTE_CHROME = "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")

library(chromote)
set_chrome_args(c("--incognito","--disable-gpu","--force-color-profile=srgb","--disable-extensions","--mute-audio")) #--incognito means that nothing will be cached

b <- ChromoteSession$new(wait_ = TRUE) # "b" stands for "browser"
Sys.sleep(runif(1, 2, 3))

b1 <- b$new_session(width = 1700, height = 1800, wait_ = TRUE) 
  
b1$Page$navigate("https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-tagline-en.svg", wait_ = TRUE) 

# $frameId
# [1] "5F81424EA4447D20D5B241571B8E40BE"

# $loaderId
# [1] "F23B3D754796D659FBFE10AC33B77EBA"

Sys.sleep(runif(1, 3, 4))

content <- b1$DOM$getDocument( )
 
page <- b1$DOM$getOuterHTML(content$root$nodeId)
page

# $outerHTML
[1] "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 117 13\"><path d=\"M89.777 3.326c.104 0 .17.039.17.092 0 0-.055.363-.055.832 0 .093.076.081.117.039.584-.594 1.3-.921 1.781-.921 1.33 0 2.3 1.27 2.301 2.651 0 1.05-.352 1.86-.963 2.457-.533.509-1.18.729-1.91.729-.41 0-.812-.072-1.131-.201-.133-.055-.182-.071-.182.098v1.403c0 1.08.143 1.13 1.064 1.185.078.077.078.352 0 .428-.558-.011-.96-.025-1.572-.025-.572 0-.91.014-1.455.025-.078-.078-.078-.353 0-.431.793-.038.936-.104.936-1.184V4.951c0-.74-.143-.818-.846-.885-.025-.078-.053-.285-.025-.363.896-.116 1.4-.233 1.77-.377zm-17.266.144c.078.078.078.353 0 .431-.479.039-.869.455-1.053.832-.688 1.46-1.26 2.8-2.301 5.305-.16.385-.33.757-.533 1.117-.467.834-.989.938-1.26.938-.352 0-.611-.209-.611-.48 0-.17.195-.561.572-.561.143 0 .193.039.377.039.324 0 .506-.116.648-.377.195-.402.354-.762.508-1.195.131-.363-.068-.961-.182-1.223l-1.473-3.419c-.354-.828-.459-.923-1.023-.976-.078-.078-.078-.353 0-.431.26.015.609.024 1.053.024.469 0 .988-.012 1.469-.024.078.078.078.353 0 .431-.797.062-.66.297-.426.846l1.152 2.703c.109.259.221.224.311.014l1.291-2.977c.203-.473-.215-.547-.625-.586-.078-.078-.078-.353 0-.431.48.015.729.024 1.184.024.363 0 .6-.012.922-.024zM105.829.002c.117 0 .17.039.17.13 0 0-.046.448-.052 1.189l-.001 6.065c0 .639.117.885.949.949.078.078.078.273 0 .352-.793.092-1.38.285-1.664.521a.492.492 0 0 1-.299 0s.014-.639.014-.768c0-.092-.094-.067-.156-.019-.637.526-1.12.785-1.625.785-1.4 0-2.21-1.17-2.211-2.771 0-.963.338-1.73.898-2.286.52-.494 1.09-.781 1.949-.781.43 0 .963.222 1.014.222.092 0 .117-.026.117-.117V1.809c0-1.09-.156-1.03-.832-1.065-.078-.076-.104-.284-.078-.391.52-.039 1.48-.221 1.807-.351zm7.457 3.372c.949 0 1.96.352 1.965 2.197v1.938c0 .6.014 1.1.52 1.105.273 0 .328-.209.404-.209.051 0 .168.131.168.222 0 .063-.467.585-1.104.585-.694 0-.924-.48-1.002-.754h-.024l-.001-.005-.258.206c-.572.441-.82.547-1.418.547-.91 0-1.64-.377-1.639-1.404 0-.884.898-1.57 2.146-1.885l1.115-.273c.039-.013.078-.064.078-.154 0-1.47-.609-1.69-1.055-1.689-.492 0-1.08.145-1.078.546 0 .146.014.224.025.263a.593.593 0 0 1 .039.231c0 .169-.195.429-.572.429-.299 0-.455-.143-.455-.455 0-.699 1.08-1.44 2.146-1.441zm-15.579.018c1.81 0 2.2 1.17 2.197 2.265 0 .143-.09.221-.246.221l-3.459-.025c0 .754.154 1.35.416 1.78.402.663.949.937 1.418.937.754 0 1.13-.207 1.609-.701.156.011.234.078.273.206-.52.676-1.22 1.13-2.211 1.131-.936 0-1.55-.312-1.988-.832-.43-.494-.609-1.2-.609-1.924 0-1.98 1.47-3.06 2.6-3.058zm-13.081-.024c2.02 0 2.73 1.57 2.73 2.926 0 1.3-.818 2.91-2.756 2.912-1.83 0-2.73-1.47-2.73-2.795 0-1.65 1-3.04 2.756-3.043zm-49.254.024c1.81 0 2.2 1.17 2.197 2.265 0 .143-.091.221-.247.221l-3.458-.025c0 .754.156 1.35.416 1.78.403.663.949.937 1.417.937.754 0 1.13-.207 1.612-.701.156.011.234.078.273.206-.52.676-1.22 1.13-2.21 1.131-.936 0-1.55-.312-1.989-.832-.429-.494-.611-1.2-.611-1.924 0-1.98 1.47-3.06 2.6-3.058zm5.85 0c1.81 0 2.2 1.17 2.197 2.265 0 .143-.091.221-.247.221l-3.458-.025c0 .754.156 1.35.416 1.78.403.663.949.937 1.417.937.754 0 1.13-.207 1.612-.701.156.011.234.078.273.206-.52.676-1.22 1.13-2.21 1.131-.936 0-1.55-.312-1.989-.832-.429-.494-.611-1.2-.611-1.924 0-1.98 1.47-3.06 2.6-3.058zm-25.009 0c1.81 0 2.2 1.17 2.197 2.265 0 .143-.091.221-.247.221l-3.458-.025c0 .754.156 1.35.416 1.78.403.663.949.937 1.417.937.754 0 1.13-.207 1.612-.701.156.011.234.078.273.206-.52.676-1.22 1.13-2.21 1.131-.936 0-1.55-.312-1.989-.832-.429-.494-.611-1.2-.611-1.924 0-1.98 1.47-3.06 2.6-3.058zm47.407-.024c1.25 0 1.99.521 1.988 1.234 0 .402-.363.571-.637.571s-.453-.117-.494-.468c-.053-.455-.156-.91-.924-.91-.857 0-1.48.857-1.482 2.288 0 1.52.795 2.48 1.742 2.481.561 0 1.12-.285 1.561-.856.117.013.221.063.273.183-.65 1.07-1.34 1.32-2.119 1.315-1.64 0-2.57-1.16-2.574-2.834 0-1.85 1.38-3 2.666-3.004zm12.037 0c1.25 0 1.99.521 1.988 1.234 0 .402-.363.571-.637.571-.271 0-.453-.117-.494-.468-.051-.455-.154-.91-.922-.91-.859 0-1.48.857-1.482 2.288 0 1.52.793 2.48 1.742 2.481.559 0 1.12-.285 1.561-.856.117.013.221.063.271.183-.648 1.07-1.34 1.32-2.119 1.315-1.64 0-2.57-1.16-2.572-2.834 0-1.85 1.38-3 2.664-3.004zm-45.836-.035c.104 0 .169.038.169.091 0 0-.065.624-.065 1.04 0 .063.039.13.117-.015.299-.506.832-1.08 1.443-1.078.546 0 .78.375.78.623 0 .326-.299.649-.611.649-.273 0-.403-.247-.533-.377-.078-.077-.182-.091-.273-.091-.156 0-.455.43-.598.637-.156.234-.312.533-.312.871v1.809c0 1.08.156 1.12 1.066 1.184.078.078.078.354 0 .43a60.72 60.72 0 0 0-1.573-.025c-.52 0-.936.014-1.482.025-.078-.076-.078-.352 0-.43.806-.053.962-.104.962-1.184V4.958c0-.719-.143-.822-.845-.886-.052-.078-.052-.285-.026-.362.897-.117 1.42-.234 1.781-.377zM80.104.002c.115 0 .168.039.168.13 0 0-.046.448-.052 1.189l-.001 6.168c0 1.08.145 1.14.938 1.184.078.078.078.352 0 .43-.561-.014-.885-.025-1.443-.025-.572 0-.91.014-1.457.025-.078-.078-.078-.352 0-.43.793-.039.938-.104.938-1.184l-.001-5.68c0-1.09-.156-1.03-.832-1.065-.078-.076-.105-.284-.078-.391.52-.039 1.49-.221 1.82-.351zM52.231.633c.039 0 .052.013.052.039.026.104.221 1.35.286 1.885a.712.712 0 0 1-.429.065c-.286-.897-.494-1.42-1.469-1.417h-1.365c-.312 0-.468.26-.468.571v2.601h1.183c1.1.006 1.14-.163 1.183-.878.078-.078.351-.078.429 0-.013.39-.026.676-.026 1.117 0 .44.013.688.026 1.145-.078.078-.351.078-.429 0-.039-.585-.078-.884-1.183-.884h-1.183V8.01c0 .353.182.56.468.56h1.768c.988 0 1.44-.768 1.703-1.703a.605.605 0 0 1 .455.064 21.02 21.02 0 0 1-.481 2.172s-.914-.022-1.543-.025h-2.963c-.21.003-1.09.015-1.643.025-.078-.078-.078-.352 0-.43.91-.039 1.13-.104 1.131-1.184V2.276c0-1.08-.221-1.15-1.131-1.185-.078-.078-.078-.353 0-.431.65.015 1.68.025 1.677.025h3.315c.312 0 .416-.013.637-.052zm56.966 2.696c.104 0 .168.039.168.092 0 0-.051.832-.051 1.479v2.592c-.001 1.08.142 1.13.935 1.181.078.078.078.352 0 .43-.559-.014-.885-.025-1.443-.025-.57 0-.908.014-1.457.025-.074-.078-.074-.352 0-.43.793-.064.938-.104.938-1.184V4.954c0-.74-.137-.816-.846-.883-.025-.078-.054-.287-.025-.364.896-.117 1.41-.234 1.781-.378zM27.199.633c.031 0 .046.009.052.039.018.099.214 1.35.282 1.885l-.403.065c-.286-.897-.494-1.42-1.469-1.417h-1.365c-.312 0-.468.13-.468.442v2.729h1.209c1.1 0 1.14-.169 1.183-.885.078-.077.351-.077.429 0-.013.391-.026.677-.026 1.119 0 .439.013.688.026 1.144-.078.078-.351.078-.429 0-.039-.585-.078-.884-1.183-.884h-1.209v2.619c0 1.08.221 1.14 1.131 1.184.078.078.078.352 0 .43-.65-.014-1.03-.025-1.677-.025-.663 0-1.05.014-1.69.025-.078-.078-.078-.352 0-.43.91-.039 1.13-.104 1.131-1.184V2.276c0-1.08-.221-1.15-1.131-1.185-.078-.078-.078-.353 0-.431.65.015 1.68.025 1.677.025h3.319c.308 0 .384-.008.611-.052zM8.398 0c.104 0 .156.039.156.13 0 0-.037.455-.039 1.3l-.009 2.992c0 .183.083.048.127 0 .793-.884 1.42-1.05 2.054-1.054.455 0 .861.156 1.079.44.303.396.351 1.03.351 1.742v1.938c0 1.06.143 1.12.871 1.184.065.078.065.352 0 .43-.559-.014-.845-.025-1.378-.025-.52 0-.78.014-1.326.025-.065-.078-.065-.352 0-.43.676-.064.806-.117.806-1.184V5.51c0-.39-.026-.743-.156-1.001-.151-.298-.424-.468-.689-.468-.512 0-1.01.28-1.508.767a.758.758 0 0 0-.221.549v2.131c0 1.08.117 1.13.777 1.184.078.078.078.352 0 .43-.547-.014-.777-.025-1.285-.025-.559 0-.892.014-1.427.025-.078-.078-.078-.352 0-.43.754-.053.907-.104.907-1.184V1.805c0-.299 0-.598-.91-.598H4.927c-.468 0-.598.233-.598.676v5.604c0 1.08.221 1.14 1.261 1.184.078.078.078.352 0 .43-.65-.014-1.1-.025-1.807-.025-.715 0-1.18.014-1.82.025-.078-.078-.078-.352 0-.43 1.04-.039 1.26-.104 1.261-1.184V1.843c0-.401-.13-.637-.598-.637H1.534C.819 1.206.65 1.361.39 2.4L0 2.337C.156 1.649.234.977.286.335l.351.052c0 .078 0 .301.273.301h5.174c1.1 0 1.26-.099 2.314-.688zm47.33 3.328c.104 0 .156.039.156.104 0 0-.065.6-.065.988 0 .183.091.052.13 0 .792-.882 1.42-1.05 2.054-1.052.455 0 .857.156 1.078.44.301.403.352 1.03.352 1.742v1.938c0 1.06.145 1.12.871 1.184.064.078.064.352 0 .43-.559-.014-.846-.025-1.377-.025-.521 0-.779.014-1.327.025-.065-.078-.065-.352 0-.43.676-.064.806-.117.806-1.184V5.51c0-.39-.026-.74-.156-1.001-.156-.299-.429-.468-.689-.468-.507 0-1.01.284-1.508.767a.765.765 0 0 0-.221.549v2.131c0 1.06.117 1.12.78 1.184.078.078.078.352 0 .43-.546-.014-.78-.025-1.287-.025-.559 0-.897.014-1.43.025-.078-.078-.078-.352 0-.43.78-.064.91-.117.91-1.184V4.953c0-.754-.143-.818-.845-.883-.026-.078-.052-.287-.026-.364.897-.117 1.43-.234 1.794-.378zm28.755.473c-1.09-.003-1.49 1.18-1.494 2.312 0 1 .494 2.67 1.846 2.666.611 0 1.4-.353 1.404-2.066 0-1.91-.637-2.91-1.756-2.912zm6.942.163c-.379 0-.91.338-1.312.754-.167.175-.208.303-.208.575v2.418c0 .47.051.545.311.778.234.209.689.273.924.273 1.46 0 1.83-1.33 1.832-2.395 0-1.47-.715-2.4-1.547-2.403zm22.819 2.084-1.032.274c-.959.254-1.23.846-1.234 1.431 0 .401.285.923.938.923.363 0 .809-.286 1.146-.561.104-.078.182-.168.182-.338V6.048zm-10.588-2.225c-.26 0-.809.039-1.209.648-.193.271-.377.793-.377 1.729 0 1.62.729 2.39 1.432 2.393.322 0 .738-.208 1.223-.624.184-.158.207-.26.207-.507V4.993c0-.402-.039-.493-.221-.701-.262-.299-.586-.469-1.055-.469zm-68.284 0c-.312 0-1.22.117-1.469 1.586l2.353-.039c.143-.002.195-.064.195-.183 0-1.09-.585-1.36-1.079-1.364zm-19.159 0c-.312 0-1.22.117-1.469 1.586l2.353-.039c.143-.002.195-.064.195-.183 0-1.09-.585-1.36-1.079-1.364zm25.009 0c-.312 0-1.22.117-1.469 1.586l2.353-.039c.143-.002.195-.064.195-.183 0-1.09-.585-1.36-1.079-1.364zm56.482 0c-.311 0-1.22.117-1.469 1.586l2.354-.039c.145-.002.195-.064.195-.183 0-1.09-.586-1.36-1.08-1.364zM108.805.665c.352 0 .623.363.623.676 0 .273-.312.624-.676.624-.312 0-.623-.338-.623-.677.001-.311.364-.623.676-.623z\"/></svg>"

I have no idea whether it's possible to download this file. I know it's possible to download a file when there's a button to trigger the download, but here there is not.

Thanks for your insights. I see what you mean; this is not a general solution - but one that works specifically with svg files because one can download their inner code and reconstruct the file. While that does not answer my more general question, I think it's certainly going to be helpful to others!

I don't believe Chrome-based browsers can be forced to save content to a file without user interaction, so less than ideal approach for any kind of automation, but you certainly can use Chrome DevTools Protocol through chromete to pull response details and data to R and write files from there.

Network.getResponseBody would allow you to access response body (binary data will be Base64 encoded)
Network.responseReceived events could be used to collect requestIds that getResponseBody expects as a parameter

library(chromote)

cs <- ChromoteSession$new()

# a list for response records
responses <- list()

# set up a callback function for responseReceived, 
# picks few details from response and stores those in global `responses` list;
# to retrieve response body, we only need requestId, stored in list names;
# returned function - `responseReceived_cancel()` - 
# can be used for disabling that callback
responseReceived_cancel <- cs$Network$responseReceived(function (msg) {
  responses[[msg$requestId]] <<- list(
    status = msg$response$status, 
    type =  msg$response$mimeType,
    url = msg$response$url)
  
  # log message
  responses[[msg$requestId]] |> 
    stringr::str_trunc(width = 60, side = "left") |> 
    paste(collapse = "\t") |> 
    cli::cli_alert_info()
})

# recommended pattern for reliable page loading from 
# https://rstudio.github.io/chromote/#loading-a-page-reliably
p <- cs$Page$loadEventFired(wait_ = FALSE)
nav_ret <- cs$Page$navigate("https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-tagline-en.svg", wait_ = FALSE)
cs$wait_for(p)
#> ℹ 200   image/svg+xml   ...g/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-tagline-en.svg
#> $timestamp
#> [1] 1278022

# check collected responses
str(responses)
#> List of 1
#>  $ 7DBF7831BED052CDC6228FA43F616F30:List of 3
#>   ..$ status: int 200
#>   ..$ type  : chr "image/svg+xml"
#>   ..$ url   : chr "https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-tagline-en.svg"

# get response body of the 1st response
resp_body <- cs$Network$getResponseBody(names(responses)[1])
str(resp_body)
#> List of 2
#>  $ body         : chr "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 117 13\"><path d=\"M89.777 3.326c.104 0 .17.039.17.092 "| __truncated__
#>  $ base64Encoded: logi FALSE

# assume basename of the url is usable as a file name
file_ <- basename(responses[[1]]$url)

# save to file,
# binary content is base64Encoded, pass it though jsonlite::base64_dec() first,
# text content (e.g svg) can be written as-is
if (resp_body$base64Encoded){
  writeBin(jsonlite::base64_dec(resp_body$body), file_)
}else{
  readr::write_file(resp_body$body, file_)
}

# list saved files
fs::dir_info(glob = "*.svg")[1:3]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   path                     type         size
#>   <fs::path>               <fct> <fs::bytes>
#> 1 wikipedia-tagline-en.svg file        9.22K

You can also process, filter and/or save responses right in the callback function.
